# Change detection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to perform a side-effect when some data changes, e.g.

```js
const useSearchResults = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    Api.search(location.query.q).then(data => setData(data));
  }, [location.query.q]);

  // Compute some derived data from `data`.
  const searchResults =
    data &&
    data.map(item => ({
      id: item.id,
      name: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`
    }));

  return searchResults;
};

const Component = () => {
  const searchResults = useSearchResults();
  useEffect(() => {
    alert('Search results have changed'); // Side-effect
  }, [searchResults]);
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(searchResults)}</pre>;
};
```

If something causes `Component` to re-render, the `alert` will fire even if the `searchResults` haven't changed because we map over the underlying stable data in `useSearchResults` creating a new instance on every render.

My initial approach would be to use `useMemo`:

```js
  // Stabilise `searchResults`'s identity with useMemo.
  const searchResults = useMemo(
    () =>
      data &&
      data.map(item => ({
        id: item.id,
        name: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`
      })),
    [data]
  );
```

However [`useMemo` has no semantic guarantee](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) so it's (theoretically) only good for performance optimisations.

Does React offer a straight forward solution to this (common?) problem?

Comment: In the past I've used reselect to derive data from a redux store which has solved this issue but that get's a little complex when considering it only memoizes 1 value at a time so if you have multiple instances of a component you need to create multiple instances of a selector which is fiddly.

Comment: Doing some research I found some detailed discussion here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15278 which lead me to https://github.com/alexreardon/use-memo-one which seems like it'd solve the issue however given that package isn't hugely popular I'm confused as to why this is a more widely documented / solved issue 

Answer (score 0):

If it's very important that the side effect doesn't re-run, you can base your comparison on a deep equality check.  We want to see that the search results are actually different results and not just a new array with the same results.

There are various implementations of a `usePrevious` hook floating around that you can use, but basically it's just a `ref`.  Save the previous version of the search results to a `ref`.  When your effect runs, see if the current results are different than the previous results.  If they are, do your side effect and update the previous to the current.

```
const Component = () => {
  const searchResults = useSearchResults();

  // create ref for previous
  const comparisonRef = useRef('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // stringify to compare
    if ( JSON.stringify(searchResults) !== JSON.stringify(comparisonRef.current) ) {
       // run side effect only if true
       alert('Search results have changed');
       // update the ref for the next check
       comparisonRef.current = searchResults;
    }
  }, [searchResults, comparisonRef]);

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(searchResults)}</pre>;
};
```

Comment: Yeah it is critical the side-effect doesn't re-run as it's an analytics event. I wanted to avoid deep equality checks as the API response can be quite large so it's not going to be great for performance (granted it doesn't re-render often right now, but who knows, somebody might add useTime or something similar which would likely require refactoring this change detection). So far I think https://github.com/alexreardon/use-memo-one is the most sane solution.